# Best Practice for Lists and Web Part Pages

Tags: 2013, list, web-part, web-part-page

I used to refer end users directly to the list they shall use. However, in blogs or on SE it often reads as content editors (or other WebParts) are put on a list. From my understanding, this does only work on a web part page, with a list web part and content editor web part.

Is it common practice to always target users to a web part page with a list view web part and not directly to the list itself? Are there any disadvantages of the latter?

Answer (score 7):

There can be many advantages if you target your users to the `Web Part Page` on which you have a view of a List. And they are as follows.

1. The independent `Web Part Page` can be branded and have a more appealing look
2. Instead of showing all of the items, Views are very useful in listing the filtered data. Which makes sense when you want your users to see only certain type of items
3. If your view is properly filtered and have a check on number of items, then it will save you from the `List View Threshold` error, Avoiding any type of error from user's sight is the best practice.
4. An independent page certainly helps, if in case you want to beautify the only view.

Answer (score 6):

To brief it is actually a good practice to refer on a different page with list view web part added onto it. Reason is you can configure the new page such that user will not be able to use ribbon options (if want to restrict from navigating through list settings)

Step to hide ribbon:

- Edit your webpart
- Select Toolbar Type to None
- Chrome Type to Border Only
- Modify List view:
- Go to Tabular View

  - uncheck "Allow individual item checkboxs

Also Set add title column with context menu in view for limited options.

Comment: How? When he clicks on the list, ribbon options are shown anyway.

Comment: You can set the webpart option such a way that ribbon cannot be displayed

Comment: Can I find the option under 'Edit Web Part'? Hiding the ribbon would be a very good idea, which I did not think about.

Comment: Updated the answer with steps

Answer (score 5):

A web part page with a list web part on it is actually exactly the same as "the list itself". When you say "the list itself", THAT is a web part page with a list view web part on it. Nothing more.

So if you want to direct your users to a list called "My List", you can direct them to the default `AllItems.aspx` page for the list, or you can direct them to a custom web part page that has list view web part on it that points to "My List". It's the same thing.

Comment: Exactly! I really can't see how anything mentioned in other two answers cannot be done on the list's `AllItems.aspx` page.